# PowerPivot for Excel failed to connect MSOLAP

Tags: ssas, powerpivot, excel-2013

Am trying to connect SQL Server Analysis Services from PowerPivot for Excel. This was working fine and if I use existing connections it works fine.  But when I try to create a new connection throw an error as below:

> Failed to connect to the Server. Reason 'MSOLAP' provider is not registered on the local machine.

Version of SQL Sever am using is 2012.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing "Microsoft® Analysis Services OLE DB Provider for Microsoft® SQL Server®"

You should be able to find the component if you search for "Microsoft® SQL Server® Feature Pack" ([SQL 2012 version (MSOLAP.5) here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=35580)) - you then need to expand the "Install Instructions" section to find the "Microsoft® Analysis Services OLE DB Provider for Microsoft® SQL Server®" section.

(For reference, MSOLAP.4 is in the SQL Server 2008 R2 feature pack)